# How to merge a pull request without reviewing the code ? (to get the github YOLO badge)

Tags: github

How to merge a pull request without reviewing the code? (to get the GitHub YOLO badge)

Comment: Just merge without looking? I think I don't understand your question.

Comment: You need to have `write` access or higher to be able to merge a PR. If you own the repository, not a problem.

Answer (score 6):

- Create a new pull request in your repo and open it
- In the top right corner at Reviewers section, request someone to review your pull request
- Merge the pull request without finishing the review.

You can check my pull request in [this repo](https://github.com/ratul-hsan/Current-Activity/pull/10) which got me the YOLO achievement badge.